# Obtaining a xml site using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I need to obtain a list of links from a sitemap.
I'm using the code below and I don't get anything back. No errors. Ultimately I would love an excel sheet with a list.

```
import bs4
from lxml import etree #added as suggested
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(site, "lxml.xml") #added as suggested

evensite = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"td"})

print(evensite)
```

After changed, this is the error obtained

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Downloads/lxml.py", line 14, in <module>
page_soup = soup(site, "lxml.xml")
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
% ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml.xml. Do you need to install a parser library?
[Finished in 1.3s]
```

Comment: Explain the difference between expected and actual outcome.

Comment: Is that the actual url you are using?

Comment: @KarlRichter I currently get nothing when I run the script. not even an error. I get the html code back when I call for it. However  I cant `find` anything from the code. I would like to get back all hyperlinks from the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried but I don't think you can parse a .xml file with `html.parser`. Have you tried using

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml-xml")
evensite = page_soup.findAll("link")
```

Comment: The weird thing is that I am currently using anaconda, I have lxml installed through anaconda. I still get this error    `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml.xml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Comment: It’s `lxml-xml` instead of `lxml.xml`. I typed it wrong at first.